# How to move the layout up when the soft keyboard is shown android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a login screen with two `EditTexts` and a login button in my layout. The problem is that, when I start typing, the soft keyboard is shown and covers the login button. How can I push the layout up or above the keyboard when it appears?

I do not want to use a `ScrollView`, just want to implement it without scrolling down. How can that be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I somehow achieved this by knowing the status of the soft keyboard on the device. i move the layout to y position when the keyboard is shown and moved back to its original position when not shown. this works fine, followed [this guidelines.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4737265/1063861)

Comment: I am able to move the layout up when keyboard shows, but unable to move to its original position while key board hides, can u help me in this.

Answer (score 62):

Set `windowSoftInputMode` property to `adjustPan` and `adjustResize`

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"> </activity>
```

Comment: This didn't work out of the box, but changing it to `<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"></activity>` got it working.

Comment: Mention which Android version you are using. Some answers may be totally useless on some versions.

Comment: as @nickiaconis said, I dont need 'adjustPan' parameter and it works for me, thank you

Comment: Is there an equivalent available for Xamarin.Forms portable project? so I don't have to do this for each individual target platform.

Comment: Only using `adjustPan` did the trick for me. Worked like charm :) Many thanks!

Comment: The setting must be one of the values listed in the following table, or a combination of one "state..." value plus one "adjust..." value. Setting multiple values in either group — multiple "state..." values, for example — has undefined results.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: This won't work if `windowFullscreen` is enabled in theme

Comment: This doesn't work if all views have fixed sizes. When I made weight `1` and height `0dp` on one of the view, my activity resized on soft input.

Answer (score 35):

Try this in the android manifest file corresponding to the activity.

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>
```

Comment: my loyout move to up first time, but when close keyboard and open again, not move.

Answer (score 27):

Use this code in `onCreate()` method:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity> didn't work for me by some reason.

Comment: This method, but use `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE` instead of ADJUST_PAN, worked for me

Answer (score 18):

only

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

in your activity tag inside Manifest file will do the trick

Comment: I am using ConstraintLayout, this solution does not work for me.

Comment: At the time of writing this answer, ConstraintLayout was not added in Android layouts. You please find any other solution on this thread that suits you best. And surely I will update my answer for ConstraintLayout once I get the time. Thanks for reporting

Answer (score 13):

Put this line in activity declaration time in manifest.xml

```
<android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

Answer (score 10):

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

add property on main layout of layout file and

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

add line in your Manifest.xml file on your Activty

its perfect work for me.

Comment: fitsSystemWindows has nothing to do with the keyboard

Comment: @TimCastelijns, in my case (fullscreen activity) it has matter. If set to `false`, views will not move up.

Answer (score 6):

Put this in your activity declaration in manifest file

`<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"> </activity>`

or if you want you can add in onCreate() method of your activity

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Comment: Manifest code is wrong, this way behavior is undefined (you set two conflict values, see offdoc: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html, `android:windowSoftInputMode` description). @kiwicomb123, choose one parameter or the system will choose for you (and this choice can change on another device / API verision)

Answer (score 3):

This is all that is needed:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> </activity>
```

Answer (score 3):

I solve this by adding code into manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".Login"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Accoding to this [guide](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html), the correct way to achieve this is by declaring in your manifest:

```
<activity name="EditContactActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">

    </activity>
```

Comment: It looks like stateVisible will cause it to open when the activity starts, so it's not necessary to actually push the keyboard up.

Answer (score 2):

When the softkeyboard appears, it changes the size of main layout, and what you need do is to make a listener for that mainlayout and within that listener, add the code `scrollT0(x,y)` to scroll up.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with xamarin, you can put this code 
`WindowSoftInputMode =Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustPan | Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustResize` in activity attribute of the MainActivity class.
For example, now the activity attribute will look like below

```
    [Activity(WindowSoftInputMode =Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustPan | Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustResize)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        //some code here.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
```

in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file where you are declaring your  activity. This will adjust your layout contents, when keyboard is shown in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of Relative layout it will adjust the view so that you can see that view while typing the text

Answer (score 0):

This works like a charm for me

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Answer (score -2):

This will definitely work for you.

**android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"**

Comment: Can you add some explanation...?

Comment: Just go to your AndroidManifest.xml file and and this tag to that activity which you want to scroll up on keyboard pop up