# Adjust layout when soft keyboard is visible

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I am developing an application for `android` devices, which manages TV channels and shows. In it there is an option for the user to add channels in the system using a custom `widget`. The widget uses `autocompleteTextView`. My layout does not adjust itself when the `soft keyboard` appears.

These are the 2 states of the layout:

[image: The state without keyboard]

[image: The state when keyboard appears]

The keyboard blocks the user from viewing the options in the dropdown and the field below it. I have already tried [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111813/how-to-move-the-layout-up-when-the-soft-keyboard-is-shown-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android/4737265#4737265). But none of them got it to work.

I want to move the layout of the widget itself, rather then the whole layout behind. How to go about this problem?

Comment: Try android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan", more options here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html  --- check the windowSoftInputMode and you have to set this in manifest to your activity

Comment: I have already tried `<activity         android:name="com.tvdashboard.channelsetup.SectionChannelSetup"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"</activity>` but its not working