# How to move up the whole layout when keyboard shown?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
        </LinearLayout>    

</FrameLayout>
```

in manifest:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

**Initial behavior:**

[image]

**Current behavior:**

[image]

**Desired behavior:**

[image]

How to achive desired behavior of layout? **adjustResize** unsuitable because this option resizes layout.

Thank you for answers!

Comment: I think you should use a scroll view as the main parent layout

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get your intention. Say there were another two buttons above and below the text view;what would your desired behaviour be? If everything moves up, how is that not adjustResize ?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to obtain that result is resize layout.
Use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: adjustResize does not suit me because this option resizes layout

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111813/how-to-move-the-layout-up-when-the-soft-keyboard-is-shown-android?rq=1). A suggestion from it:

Set Window SoftInput Mode property to adjustPan and adjustResize

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"> </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one in your manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateUnchanged"
```

Answer (score 1):

the check if the layout that contain EditText and Button is RelativeLayout.

Comment: try to replace LinearLayout to RelativeLayout

Comment: Try to replace the frame layout to relative layout

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `FrameLayout` to `RelativeLayout` with `alignParentBottom="true"` property in your `LinearLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
        </LinearLayout>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to implement that with `adjustPan`, because from the [official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

Your `Button` is below your current focus `EditText`

Answer (score 1):

by removing below line from activity and  **android:windowSoftInputMode**  from manifest, I got whole layout scrolling which was previously hiding by

> this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

please check this output video link:
https://mega.nz/#!TpRCWZjY!TqDzv0Yn3Q24PR1JAdH8kRVeDf2iSa1LQbNBgF0SVHk

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a simple way to do this.  At least not as simple as setting a flag.
I had a similar situation of wanting the keyboard to rise to the level of Views well below the selected EditText.  I ended up using this answer:
[How to check visibility of software keyboard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android/4737265#4737265)

and manually adjusting my View sizes when the keyboard becomes visible.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this property in activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```