# Scrollview when keyboard is open height not taking auto

Tags: android

**Help needed**
I am getting very surprising issue,please help me to find solution.
Here is my code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f5f5f5"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_normal"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_normal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            app:queryHint="@string/search_hint" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/healthtips" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_normal"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_normal"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_askexpert"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="@string/ask_expert"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**when keyboard is opened and closed, the height of scrollview not working  and the area where keyboard opens remains as empty**
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111813/how-to-move-the-layout-up-when-the-soft-keyboard-is-shown-android

Comment: yea, finally found the sollution , in oncreate() getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);