# Fragment Layout does not move up on keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, keyboard

I use a viewpage to view fragment, which are switched by tabs.

This is my `fragment_details_comment.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/chat_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    tools:context=".activities.DetailsActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/comments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@drawable/chat_divider"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomlayout"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/no_comments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/no_comments"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingStart="12dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/input">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/emoji_button"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_tag_faces_white"
                android:tint="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/comment_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:hint="@string/type_your_message"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColorHint="#c4c0bd"
                android:background="@null"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/send_comment"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/input_circle_normal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this the `activity_details.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.mysampleapp.details">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_save_white" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

(The fab is hidden in the `fragment_details_comment.xml` and only shown in the other fragment!)

When I touch on the EditText field, my keyboard is shown and is displayed on top of my content.

[image]

[image]

So I googled, how to change that.

So I found this:
[How to move the layout up when the soft keyboard is shown android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9112735/2977288)

I placed this line of code into my Android Manifest file and placed it inside my activity config:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.DetailsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activities.MainActivity" />

    </activity>
```

That didn't work, nothing changed at all.

Then I tried another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15063495/2977288

This does work partly: I moves up my content, but also my toolbar and my tabs I'm using. Additionally the content is not completely moved up, so something like 20dp are still covered by the keyboard

Is it maybe because of the fragment or the viewpage?

Comment: @Zoker- Any solutions to this issue?

Comment: Sadly not, but I'm not working in the app right now. Maybe if I upgrade the dependencies etc it'll work

Comment: any solutions for this?