# Preventing linear layout from moving up when soft keyboard is visible

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, window-soft-input-mode

I have a layout something like this -

```
<Relativelayout

<ScrollView
           <LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</Relative>
```

If you want to look at full code it is [here](http://pastebin.com/Y2Un8PKy)

The problem is that whenever soft keyboard is visible on screen the linear layout below `ScrollView` lifts up and blocks the view inside of `ScrollView` .

What I want is that if soft keyboard is visible nothing lifts up but I can still scroll through `ScrollView`.

**EDIT**

May be i was not clear before ....as everybody is saying to change this

`android:windowSoftInputMode` to

> adjustPan | adjustResize or combnation of state and adjust values

I already did this ..this prevents lifting up of LinearLayout below the ScrollView but  it also blocks scrolling feature of ScrollView .

**EDIT 2**

as @WritingForAnroid suggests in answer i made ScrollView parent view in layout and that solved my problem but then as scrollview always takes height in wrap_content manner so bottom view that was previously aligned with the bottom of screen is not aligned now so  how do i align bottom view with bottom of screen if ScrollView is parent view .

ScreenShot - [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtPlP.jpg)

Please help ! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can specify keyboard behaviour here: https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html#Respond

Comment: i did this already but it didn't help ...all options comes down to this either i am unable to scroll in scrollview or linearlayout lifts up.

Comment: Have you tried `android:scrollbars="vertical"` inside `Scroll View` ?

Comment: please check  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" in menifest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111813/how-to-move-the-layout-up-when-the-soft-keyboard-is-shown-android

Comment: i tried all suggestions of yours but still not resolved

Comment: what is correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Change this

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

To

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Answer (score 0):

Make Scrollview as parent view and add this line to your activity in manifest file

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: ok  your method works...but now this happened - [this](http://imgur.com/a/xJX8X)....How do i make bottom view to be aligned with bottom of screen