# how to move the entair screen up when keyboard enabled?

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to scroll up the entair screen up when keyboard opened like below.How to do that?

https://www.screencast.com/t/34JwVngLdYbU

Comment: use  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in your activity tag n see

Comment: Please refer [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964789/move-layouts-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111813/how-to-move-the-layout-up-when-the-soft-keyboard-is-shown-android) for your refrence

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize this one working fine

Comment: but  if i implement in my project not woking.not at all scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` with activity tag in manifest file.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" not working for me

Comment: use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" and put your layout in scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

and put complete layout in `LinearLayout` and `ScrollView` & define

```
layout_height="0dp"
layout_weight="1"
```

**Note:** No view have parameter `layout_height="match_parent"`

Answer (score 0):

I had also same issue just adding a single line to my AndroidManifest  file's activity.

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.YOURACTIVITY"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible"/>
```

If you want keyboard should appear with start Activity then use `stateVisible` otherwise use `stateHidden`.

Here the most important value is the `adjustResize`. This will shift the whole UI up to give room for the softkeyboard.