# View at the bottom of RelativeLayout does not stick to the keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <AppBarLayout>

        ...

    </AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tool_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/editor_item_size"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/custom_setting_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tool_list"
        android:layout_below="@id/appBarLayout">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/category_area"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp">

                ...

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/title_area"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/category_area"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/editor_item_size"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/title_edit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title_area"
                android:background="@color/colorDivider" />

            <jp.wasabeef.richeditor.RichEditor
                android:id="@+id/editor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/divider"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my writeActivity.xml

when i clicked title_edit like this.

[image: before]

i want this flow like below picture.

[image: what i want]

but it's doesn't work way i wanted it to.

it work like this.

[image: what i don't want]

i think i was able to do it this way before, but i think i got it wrong.

i've added a scrolling view, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

how can I do picture 2 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move the layout up when the soft keyboard is shown android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111813/how-to-move-the-layout-up-when-the-soft-keyboard-is-shown-android)

Comment: uhm...is it cause by richeditor?
it inherited webview.

Answer (score 1):

in your app manifest file for that activity use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the root RelativeLayout. Hopefully that'll do it

Comment: Bugger, that should do it :/ Can you show your manifest file?

Comment: @monoz sure, wait a minute

Comment: added a note from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/21860837/6407116 to use fitsSystemWindows in your root relative layout. Also try without the adjustPan temporarily

Comment: Must be to do with the rich editor. I'd suggest to comment it out in the xml and test the keyboard with tool_list working correctly, then put it back in. sorry :(

Comment: thank you for help. i'll considering change richeditor to edittext.